# blender 2.81 strech the mesh in pose mode after parent object with bones

Tags: rigging

I build a human and then used the human meta rig, parent by auto-weight. Then go to pose mode to test the rigging, the mesh do move with the bones but some bones strech the mesh too much, for instance: the arm bone that connect the arm and the shoulder, as I move that arm bone, the entire arm mesh got streched very long, the spine bone connect the leg and the spine, as I move that spine bone, the entire human mesh got streched long, and some part of the human mesh just don't move with some bones, for example, one of the spine bone in the middle of the spine, as I move this bone, the cape I made for this human does not move with it.

Comment: need waaaay more information, screenshots would help.
One quick thing to check: open the console and see if there are dependency cycles in your armature (Window -> Toggle System Console (Windows)) on mac and Linux, it's the default way to open any console.

Comment: What's your question? This is a **Question** and *Answer* site: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask